# Why is a tag too similar to itself?

Tags: bug, tags, tag-synonyms

I wanted to tag [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1830385/zsh-handling-of-substring-changed) with [variables](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/variables). When I typed "vari" the only suggestion was [environment-variables](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/environment-variables).  Since the description says "system-wide" and my question concerned variables within the scope of a script, I said "yes" to creating the tag `variables`.

However, when I tried to post the question, I got the following error:

[image: The tag 'variables' is too similar to 'variables']

Why did this happen? Is it a bug?

Comment: the tl;dr of the linked QA: you get the odd message due to an old synonym; and we don't have a `[variables]` tag as it's too generic for the site's scope

Comment: Variables is pretty much a meta tag that requires some other tag to describe what kind of variables you are talking about. If you are talking about variables within `zsh` then the tag `zsh` is absolutely required as variables may act subtly differently to, say, variables in bash even though they may be functionally equivalent. As such the variables tag is redundant in and of itself.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason for a tag called variables.  It's unncessary. A question about a shell script, doesn't need to have a tag, for the variables contained within the script itself. Your question about a zsh bash script is fine using the tags you have selected.

Comment: The above error message is caused by [this synonym](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nmirn.png) to a non-existent tag. Mods could remove the synonym, but ultimately - as others have stated - we don't need a [variables] tag, so if leaving it in place prevents it's creation, then it's probably for the best.